# Mpiexec by linux system

Tags: c++, c, mpi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openmpi

Hello I have this error message when running

> nazir@DESKTOP-3EOPC1I:/mnt/c/MPI/MPI1$ mpiexec explicitpar.c -4 explicitpar
>
> Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but
> failed.  Open MPI checks many things before attempting to launch a
> child process, but nothing is perfect. This error may be indicative
> of another problem on the target host, or even something as silly as
> having specified a directory for your application. Your job will now
> abort.
>
> Local host:        DESKTOP-3EOPC1I
> Working dir:       /mnt/c/MPI/MPI1
> Application name:  /mnt/c/MPI/MPI1/explicitpar.c
> Error:             Exec format error
>
> mpiexec was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an
> error:
>
> Error code: 1
> Error name: (null)
> Node: DESKTOP-3EOPC1I
>
> when attempting to start process rank 0.
>
> > ---
>
> 2 total processes failed to start
> [DESKTOP-3EOPC1I:04039] 1 more process has sent help message help-orte-odls-default.txt / execve error
> [DESKTOP-3EOPC1I:04039] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
>
> 1. List item

How can I try to debug this or provide more information to help debug this?

Comment: what is `explicitpar.c`? a source file? a binary?

Comment: explicit par.c ist name der file

Comment: ??? Try `mpirun -np 4 ./explicitpar`

Comment: I have this error message

Comment: There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4
slots that were requested by the application:

  ./explicitpar.c

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.

Comment: A "slot" is the Open MPI term for an allocatable unit where we can
launch a process.  The number of slots available are defined by the
environment in which Open MPI processes are run:

Comment: 1. Hostfile, via "slots=N" clauses (N defaults to number of
     processor cores if not provided)
  2. The --host command line parameter, via a ":N" suffix on the
     hostname (N defaults to 1 if not provided)

Comment: 2. The --host command line parameter, via a ":N" suffix on the
     hostname (N defaults to 1 if not provided)
  3. Resource manager (e.g., SLURM, PBS/Torque, LSF, etc.)

Comment: 4. If none of a hostfile, the --host command line parameter, or an
     RM is present, Open MPI defaults to the number of processor cores

Comment: `mpirun --oversubscribe -np 4 ./explicitpar`

Comment: I have this massage

Comment: WARNING: Linux kernel CMA support was requested via the
btl_vader_single_copy_mechanism MCA variable, but CMA support is
not available due to restrictive ptrace settings.

The vader shared memory BTL will fall back on another single-copy
mechanism if one is available. This may result in lower performance.

  Local host: DESKTOP-3EOPC1I

Comment: An error occurred in MPI_Cart_create

Comment: reported by process [1037828097,0],on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind,  MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort, and potentially your MPI job),3 more processes have sent help message help-btl-vader.txt / cma-permission-denied

Comment: Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages, 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal